# Checking for outliers in multinomial logistic regression

Tags: regression, logistic, multiple-regression, outliers

Do I have to check for outliers in variables that have been recoded in categories? for example, I have variable "age" as a predictor and there is a lady of 76 years old when the mean age is around 25. but I have categorized the age variable to >30 and <30 and only included this new variable in my analysis. should I remove the lady and categorize again, or it won't affect the analysis?

Answer (score 1):

Before removing her, I suggest to consider whether it makes sense to call the old lady an outlier. Are individuals with a high age relevant for your study?

If not, then you could remove this data point from the analysis.

If this age group is relevant, do you expect the age group, for example, >50 to behave differently than >30? If so, you should create an additional category. However, if there is only 1 data point, you would have very little data, so you might consider excluding the data point for this reason.

Comment: Thank you, yet one question. Doesn't categorizing continuous variables reduce the impact of outliers in the final model?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by 'the impact of outliers'. Can you shortly explain what you are trying to model (the dependent variable, your hypothesis how age correlates with the outcome) and why having a person of 76 years in the dataset is a problem? Just because there is one person in the dataset that has a higher age doesn't necessarily mean that it is a problem.

Comment: I am trying to assess the overall health status of pregnant women and it's predictors. It's not just age that has certain outliers, it was just an examples. I am using about ten predictor variables. I am new to this, so I can be certainly wrong, but outliers can affect the odds ratio calculated in the model quite drastically if I use them as continuous variables. My question is this, If I transform them to nominal or ordinal variables, will the outlier still affect the model and the calculated odds ratio?

Comment: If you turn a continuous variable into a categorical variable, you throw away information. If you put 30 year olds and 70 year olds in the same category and 70years+ people have dramatically worse health, you will overestimate the bad health-probability for 30 year olds and underestimate the probability for 70 year olds because you assign the same probability to everyone in the group age>30.
So, yes it will still affect your analysis even after creating categories like age<=30 & age>30.
Question: 76 years and pregnant - sure it is not a typo??

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I understand now. PS re:Question I believe its either a world record or a typo... I am going with typo. although as I mentioned, problem was not limited to this special lady. thanks again.